# which sentence is correct? has left, left or leaves?

Tags: past-tense

I am confused with this:

"Long after **he has left**, she finds out that it has been stolen."

"Long after **he left**, she finds out that it has been stolen."

"Long after **he leaves**, she finds out that it has been stolen."

I don't really know which one is the correct one. Please help. Thank you :)

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the the second part in present simple tense?

Comment: Yes, it is. The second part must be in present simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'**after he leaves**' = context is present, but describes just a condition that hasn't yet happened.
e.g. after he leaves, let's set his bed on fire.

'**after he has left**' = context is present tense, but describes a condition that happened in the (implied recent) past.
e.g. after he has left, he realises that he **has** left his wallet behind (or he **doesn't have** his wallet - to make the present tense clearer)

'**after he left**' = the story context is past. The 'after' has no bearing on the tense change.
e.g. After he left the building, he realise**d** he left his wallet behind. He knew he **was** a dumbass, but he **didn't** believe he was this dumb.

The latter part is present tense - so "Long after he **has left**..." is the right prefix.

Comment: 'after he has left' can also describe a *future* moment (i.e. he hasn't left yet), more usually rendered as 'once he has left ...".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a part of a scenario script for a movie or something

In this case l'd suggest using the "he left" referring to an actor in another scene

Comment: They all say the same thing and they are all fine for purposes of describing a timeline (e.g. in a script).